# Oracle SQL Merge Multiple rows With Same ID But Out of Order Identifiers

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a distinct list of parts to do analysis on in a table. The table contains a column of Part IDs and a column of Identifiers. The Identifiers are separated within the same entry by pipes but unfortunately the Identifiers are out of order. I'm not sure if this is possible but any help would be greatly appreciated!

For example (currently Both ID and Identifiers are VARCHAR2)

```
ID  Identifiers
1   |1|2|
1   |2|1|
2   |3|A|1|B|
2   |B|1|3|A|
3   |1|3|2|
3   |1|5|
3   |2|1|3|
4   |AA|BB|1|3A|
4   |1|3A|AA|BB|
```

and I need the query to return

```
ID  Identifiers
1   |1|2|
2   |3|A|1|B|
3   |1|5|
3   |1|3|2|
4   |1|AA|BB|3A|
```

It does not matter what specific order the identifiers are ordered in as long as all contents within that identifier are the same. For example, |1|5| or |5|1| doesn't matter but I need to see both entries |1|5| and |1|3|2. My original thought was to create separate out the identifiers into separate columns and then alphabetically concatenate back into one column but i'm not sure...thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you care if the query returns the identifiers in an order that doesn't match any of the original rows? For example alphabetically (with digits falling wherever they may)?

Comment: Nope they can be returned in any order!

Comment: And, can there be duplicates among the identifiers in a single row? And if so, do you need to repeat the duplicates exactly the right number of times, or can you consolidate them?

Comment: There shouldn't be any duplicates among the identifiers but if so, you can consolidate them. Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: ... and one more - can there be duplicate rows, like `'1' '|1|2|'` appearing in the base table more than once?

Comment: @mathguy Nope there shouldn't be any duplicates in the base table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (assuming there are no duplicate rows in the input table - if there are, the solution needs to be modified a bit).

In the solution I build the test_table for testing (it is not part of the solution), and I build another factored subquery in the WITH clause. This works in Oracle 11 and above. For earlier versions of Oracle, the subquery defined as `prep` needs to be moved as a subquery within the final query instead.

```
with
     test_table ( id, identifiers ) as (
       select '1', '|1|2|'        from dual union all
       select '1', '|2|1|'        from dual union all
       select '2', '|3|A|1|B|'    from dual union all
       select '2', '|B|1|3|A|'    from dual union all
       select '3', '|1|3|2|'      from dual union all
       select '3', '|1|5|'        from dual union all
       select '3', '|2|1|3|'      from dual union all
       select '4', '|AA|BB|1|3A|' from dual union all
       select '4', '|1|3A|AA|BB|' from dual
     ),
     prep ( id, identifiers, token ) as (
       select id, identifiers, regexp_substr(identifiers, '[^|]+', 1, level)
       from   test_table
       connect by level <= regexp_count(identifiers, '\|') - 1
           and prior identifiers = identifiers
           and prior sys_guid() is not null
     )
select distinct id, 
       '|' || listagg(token, '|') within group (order by token) || '|'
                                                as identifiers
from   prep
group by id, identifiers
order by id, identifiers    --  ORDER BY is optional
;
```

**Output**:

```
ID  IDENTIFIERS
--- --------------------
1   |1|2|
2   |1|3|A|B|
3   |1|2|3|
3   |1|5|
4   |1|3A|AA|BB|

5 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! Is there any way to make the query take less time to run or have an estimate for how long it should run for? The table I'm working on is about 900k rows and the query provided been running (now for a bout 45 minutes) a lot longer than any of my previous queries. Thanks!

Comment: It depends not only on the number of rows, but also on how many identifiers there are in each row. But it taking a (very) long time is expected, the operations are quite time-consuming. This is the very high cost to pay for the data violating the "first normal form" - it shouldn't be in that form in the first place. With that said - did you run it on a smaller case first, say with 2k rows instead of 900k? To get an idea for what to expect?