# ; With tablename as (..) equivalent in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I am new to Oracle, and i am trying to replicate a very useful type of query  I always used with SQL Server.

I am trying to find the equivalent in Oracle for this query

```
; With tablename as (
Select 
Column1 ,
Column2
From table1
) 
, with tablename2 as (
Select 
column3,
Column4
)
Select 
Column 2 ,
column 4
from Tablename t1
left outer join tablename t2
on t1.column1 = t2.column3
```

Comment: That's the same in Oracle - except that Oracle follows the SQL standard and puts the statement termination character (the `;`) where it belongs: at the end (and the second `with` is invalid - even in SQL Server). See the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABCGAAJ (a common table expression is introduced using the keyword `with`, not using `;with`)

Comment: Also, note that you have `Column 2` and `Column 4` while it should be `Column2` and `Column4`.

Comment: You will find lots of solutions on this site that use the proper Oracle syntax for this - here is one I offered just yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366876/oracle-sql-merge-multiple-rows-with-same-id-but-out-of-order-identifiers/40367201#40367201  (That answer illustrates another nice feature - you can put the column aliases at the top - which unfortunately requires Oracle 11.2 or higher.)

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors (spaces in column names, missing FROM, ...).
This should work:

```
WITH tablename AS (SELECT Column1, Column2 FROM table1),
     tablename2 AS (SELECT column3, Column4 FROM table2)
SELECT Column2, column4
  FROM Tablename t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column3
```